# Using CSV Data Set Config with IncludeController leads to variables not getting replaced

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter script that reads a csv file and loads entries into the variable name n_id. When I run this script with a thread group, it works just fine. So the script would look like:

```
Test Plan
- CSV Data Set Config
- Test Fragment
  - HTTP Sampler that uses the ${n_id} variable
```

When I validate this script with a thread group, it works perfectly and the ${n_id} variable gets replaced. However, when I want to use it in a script with an IncludeController, with a structure like:

```
Test Plan
- Thread Group
  - Include Controller
    - link to the previously described script
```

and I try and validate *that* script, which should operate in an identical manner, I get errors in all my samplers that use the ${n_id} variable. For some reason, it's not getting replaced. All my other user variables still work fine, it is just this CSV Config that does not replace variables. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Adding appropriate tags to your post can cause more people to see your post.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the IncludeController only reads the test fragment. So the script should have been structured as:

```
Test Plan
- Test Fragment
  - CSV Data Set Config
  - HTTP Sampler that uses the ${n_id} variable
```